# Restoring System directories permissions

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I accidentally changed the permission of all the directories in / folder. Because of this many of the services are not properly working. How to restore them back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the permissions with all installed RPM packages, that should make most things work again.

```
for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setperms $p; done
for p in $(rpm -qa); do rpm --setugids $p; done
```

Run as root.