# Is there a way to fix all permissions of the directory on Fedora?

Tags: sudo, fedora, fedora-33

I accidentally broke the file permissions of /usr using chmod. There is X on each folder and when I try to open it shows like this:

[image]

Now I can not use sudo to fix it because it gives this error:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 14 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0.
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

I also can not use chmod in /usr file since it needs sudo.

Is there a way to fix all permissions of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restoring System directories permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287671/restoring-system-directories-permissions)

Comment: No, because I can not run anything as root

Comment: You can do this by booting from a live CD (like the installer), mounting the filesystem, and running the above command within a chroot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from Live Fedora USB

Locate `/run/media/VOLUME_NAME` of the Linux HDD

```
#su 
#mount -o remount,rw /run/media/VOLUME_NAME 
#chown root:root -R /run/media/VOLUME_NAME/usr 
#chmod 4755 /run/media/VOLUME_NAME/usr/bin/sudo
```

Then reboot to the OS

```
#sudo rpm --setugids –a 
#sudo rpm --setperms -a
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall fedora from the start. But if there is any way to handle this, I would like to hear.